# C++, Constructor with istream on a derivate class

Tags: c++, constructor, stream

I have a problem with a derived class who have a constructor with a istream in parameter.

***Reference.cpp***_

```
....
Reference::Reference(istream& p_is)
{...}
....
```

***Livre.h***_

```
class Livre : public Reference
    {

    private:
    void verifieInvariant() const;
    std::string m_editeur;
    std::string m_isbn;

    public:

    Livre(
        const std::string& p_cote,
        const std::string& p_theme,
        const std::string& p_titre,
        const std::string& p_auteurs,
        int p_anneeEdition,
        const util::Date& p_dateAcquisition,
        const std::string& p_editeur,
        const std::string& p_isbn);

    Livre(std::istream& p_is);
...
```

***Livre.cpp***

```
....
Livre::Livre(std::istream& p_is)
{

    Reference(std::istream& p_is);
    string editeur ="";

    string isbn = "";
    string buffer = "";
    getline(p_is, buffer);
    getline(p_is, editeur);
    getline(p_is, isbn);

    m_editeur = editeur;
    m_isbn = isbn;  
}
```

Ok so my problem here it's simple. The compiler doesn't let me create another constructor with `istream` for the derived class Livre. My Reference class is an abstract one and I need to call the constructor with stream of the Reference in the constructor Livre to complete the information. The other option I have is to write over like

```
Reference::Reference(std::istream& p_is)
{...}
```

into my Livre.cpp. So if someone can explain to me a better way to do that I would really appreciate. I know I have a lot of code but it's not easy to explain the problem. Thanks guys.

Comment: be careful, the correct way to chain constructors is `Livre(std::istream &p_is): Reference(p_is) {...}`.

Comment: @didierc, The only way to chain them is that.

Comment: @chris sure, but seeing the presented code, wouldn't you infer that the intent was to chain them?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's the problem, but I believe the correct way to do this is to rewrite

```
Livre::Livre(std::istream& p_is)
{
    Reference(std::istream& p_is);
    /* ... */
}
```

as

```
Livre::Livre(std::istream& p_is) : Reference(p_is);
{
    /* ... */
}
```